# I've created a scatter plot with plotly/dash in python and I would like to be able to filter the table next to it by clicking at certain scatter point

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash, scatter-plot

```
app = Dash(__name__)
colors = {
    'background': '#ededed',
    'text': '#0b1710'
}
fig = px.scatter(df, x="AverageTime", y="Machine",
                 size="Jobs", color="Category", hover_name="MaxTime",
                 log_x=False, log_y=False, size_max=70, labels={
                     "AverageTime": "Average time since last update(min)",
                     "Machine": "Machine code",
                     "MaxTime": "Longest time since last update(min)",
                     "Category": "Department",
                 }, title="Vision Labs Orders Movement Tracking")

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='graph',
        figure=fig
    )
])
fig.update_layout(
    plot_bgcolor=colors['background'],
    paper_bgcolor=colors['background'],
    font_color=colors['text'],
    autosize=True,
    height=900
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

to
This is my current code for better understanding. If I knew how to fetch data needed to filter the table by clicking on the point I would be able to establish that in pure python probably

Comment: Where is the table next to it and what is the data inside this table?

Comment: I can JOIN second table and it contain job number, location, and time till updated. My bottleneck is how to retrieve the data on click so I can use them to filter table